# hprof profiler output doesn't include line numbers regardless of `lineno` value

Tags: java, profiling, hprof

I'm running

```
java -cp some:jars:out \
-agentlib:hprof=cpu=times,format=a,file=java.hprof.txt,lineno=y,doe=y com.foo.Benchmark \
< /dev/null
```

and in the output I get stack frames without line numbers

```
THREAD START (obj=50000150, id = 200002, name="HPROF gc_finish watcher", group="system")
THREAD START (obj=50000151, id = 200001, name="main", group="main")
THREAD START (obj=50000281, id = 200003, name="Thread-1", group="main")
THREAD END (id = 200003)
THREAD END (id = 200001)
THREAD START (obj=500002a5, id = 200004, name="DestroyJavaVM", group="main")
THREAD END (id = 200004)
TRACE 307081:
        com.foo.Benchmark.methodName(Benchmark.java:Unknown line)
        com.foo.Benchmark.anotherMethodName(Benchmark.java:Unknown line)
        ...
```

If I change `lineno=y` to `lineno=n` I still get `Unknown line`.

I compiled the classes with `-g`.  My `javac` looks like

```
javac -g -Xlint -encoding UTF-8 -source 1.5 -d out -classpath ... src/main/com/foo/*.java
```

I checked the `.class` files to make sure they have line numbers:

```
javap -classpath out -c -l com.foo.Benchmark
```

shows plenty of things like

```
  LineNumberTable: 
   line 1077: 0
   line 1078: 8
   line 1079: 14
   line 1080: 21
   line 1082: 23
   line 1083: 31
   line 1084: 43
```

Am I using some flag combination that prevents line number output?

Answer (score 2):

I faced exactly the same problem, but compiling the source with `-g` helped. After compiling with `-g`, I see the line numbers like this (which I don't see otherwise, without `-g` option) -

```
LineNumberTable:
 line 16: 0
 line 17: 8
 line 18: 12
 line 19: 20
 line 18: 29
 line 21: 35
```

Now, if I run this -

```
java -cp "./build/classes" -agentlib:hprof=heap=sites,depth=20  org.sample.welcome.Main a b c
```

I do get the line numbers for the user-defined classes. Even though I am not sure what's going wrong in your case, these are my observations -

- Using javac without `-g`: If I have `-lineno` (default `y`) set to `y`, I still don't see the line numbers for most of the classes except for the user-defined classes (`Main` in the above case). If I've set `-lineno` to `n`, then I won't see line numbers for any of the classes anyway.
- Using javac with `-g`: If I have `-lineno` set to `y`, I can see the line numbers for all the classes (not sure what's going wrong in your case).

The only documentation I could find for [HPROF](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html) doesn't say anything beyond this. I think one option would be to try with fewer optional arguments and see the results.

Note: I'm using JDK 1.6 in the above example

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I no longer have this benchmark set up to run easily, but I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: Mike's example uses `cpu=times` option, yours -- `heap=sites`. The later option does output the line number, the first does NOT.